# "Could not load assembly" - in a project that doesn't uses that assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So I've got a Xamarin.Forms app with four projects:

- *MyApp*: PCL: shared app code
- *MyApp.Core*: PCL: shared business logic, view models, etc
- *MyApp.Droid* Xamarin.Android
- *MyApp.iOS* Xamarin.iOS

Given the transition of the community from PCL profiles to .NET Standard, I decided to switch too (netstandard2.0), in my two shared projects, so I can use the most recent, cutting-edge packages from the caring community that drops PCL compatibility everywhere.

The migration of the two PCL projects is successful but one error is left **in the MyApp.Droid project**:

```
Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers, Version=2.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
Nom de fichier : 'ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers.dll'
   à Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel)
   à Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver resolver)    MyApp.Droid
```

I use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) and [ReactiveUI.Fody](https://github.com/kswoll/ReactiveUI.Fody) in *MyApp.Core*, the only place where I need them. Back when it was based on a PCL profile, the Fody packages were only installed in that project and that worked fine.

After the migration, this error popped and I don't understand why it happens in the *MyApp.Droid* project. It does not need it. I also can't find any reference to Fody in that project.

What I tried:

- clean solution
- rebuild solution
- deleted packages folder
- deleted all obj/bin folders
- deleted .vs folder at root
- restarted VS
- reboot
- tried on another PC

The project builds if I add Fody and ReactiveUI.Fody to *MyApp.Droid*. But that's a hack, I want to understand why this particular project suddenly requires that package and explain him, face to face, that he doesn't need it.

Comment: May be a dumb question but is there some old config file referencing these?

Comment: Apparently not. Here the results of a search for "ReactiveUI.Fody" in the whole solution folder after a full manual clean: https://pastebin.com/cshk0mPR
Everything is in MyApp.Core. But rebuilding from that still give the error...